# How to Remove the Restart Notification (One Time)

Tags: notification, reboot

Sometimes, when I upgrade my kernel or remove older kernels, the system nags me to reboot. I'm aware of this, and I don't want to reboot most of the time. I've notice this not only happens with the `update-manager`, but also with `cairo-dock`. How can I remove this notification, not forever, but for this time.

Comment: Isn't there a Remind me Later option?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't permanently remove it.

Comment: You mean it comes back before a reboot?

Comment: I guess you could try `sudo killall -9 update-manager` and see if the notification goes away. As long as no updates are being installed, this should be safe.

Comment: Yes but this happens with Cairo-Dock too. I want to remove it for everything.

Comment: Does the `cairo-dock` restart dialog look the same? I'm pretty sure it's updated through the update manager, as well, and that killing that will work.

Comment: No, it shows a little popup with a check and an X, saying to reboot "after the update is finished". When I hover over the icon it says "*** System Reboot Required ***". With a blue arrow over the icon.

Comment: Does hitting the X make it disappear until the next update, or does it only disappear for a bit? (bear with me).

Comment: It only disappears for a bit.

Comment: Well it doesn't seem like it's possible to get rid of that notification, but you can check the settings just in case. If you haven't rebooted for so long after an update that the app reminds you, you may want to consider rebooting.

Answer (score 3):

OK so I have been researching and experimenting, and here's what you need to do. Delete the following files, and optionally restart any process that's nagging you.

```
/var/run/reboot-required
/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I know that StackOverflow discourages such "thanks!" comments, but I was going nuts with OCD looking at the reboot prompt and now there's complete peace of mind. :-) And yes, in due time, I will reboot and remember to upgrade the kernel.