# Which updates can I do without having to reboot

Tags: 16.04, updates, reboot, ubuntu-mate

My current situation does not allow me to reboot my computer for a while. So how do I know which updates I can do without needing to do a reboot later? Should I just do every update which doesn't include the word kernel? Or ...?

I guess I can also update everything and just not reboot, but somehow that does not feel as clean ... Also don't want to be annoyed the whole time by the popup telling me to reboot.

Comment: Ubuntu version?

Comment: Most updates not including kernel do not need reboot, but running programs will not be updated till they are restarted(like browsers).  Non running programs will be updated.  Depending on time frame can put off updates, but might be leaving your system open to security holes.  There was one admin that thought he could get away without rebooting for more than year, found out he left a hole open in system that a reboot would have prevented.  Ubuntu does have a non reboot system, but I don't know enough about it.

Comment: How long is "for a while?" An hour? A month?

Comment: @Graham 16.04 (in Mate desktop environment)

Comment: @user535733 Couple of days or weeks, until I can manage to get to the office.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Remove the Restart Notification (One Time)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754658/how-to-remove-the-restart-notification-one-time)

Comment: @user535733 Not really. But the question has become sort of  moot. I've found a way to restart my computer without ruining the processes which were/are running. But thanks for the help anyway.